# IRanges output length not equal to input

Tags: bioconductor, genomicranges

I want create a `IRanges` with a exists `data.table`

```
ranges <- IRanges::IRanges(
        start = x$position,
        wdith = 1
    )

length(ranges)
[1] 31253
```

However, My `data.table` is a table with 31548 line

```
> dim(x)
[1] 31548     8
```

also `x$position` length is

```
> length(x$position)
[1] 31548
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is because of many duplicated value in `x$position`

```
sum(duplicated(x$position))
[1] 13998
```

But I am trying to create a GRanges by:

```
GenomicRanges::GRanges(
    seqnames = x$contig,
    ranges = IRanges::IRanges(
        start = x$position,
        wdith = 1
    )
```

In fact each duplicated `x$position` have different `x$chrom` value, but `IRanges::IRanges` remove them, so its not work.

My bypass solution is use `makeGRangesFromDataFrame` instead